# Query multiple joins sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.1

I am generating a query with sql alchemy part by part. I have this object that is working very well for a query with only one join:

**I have an ORM model, but I cannot use primary keys setted because are not real.

```
q = select( self.selectObj._select
    ).select_from(
        self.joinObj._join
    ).where(
        and_(*self.whereObj._where)
    ).group_by(
        *self.selectObj._groupby
    ).order_by(
        self.selectObj._orderby
    ).limit(
        self.selectObj._limit
    ).having(
        self.selectObj._having
)
```

I have this method for generate the joins:

```
def get_joins(self, first, leftTable, rightTable, leftTableColumn, rightTableColumn, outer):
    if first:
        self._join = join(leftTable, rightTable, leftTableColumn == rightTableColumn, full=outer)
        first = False
    else:
        self._join = self._join + join(leftTable, rightTable, leftTableColumn == rightTableColumn, full=outer)
```

I don´t know, how can I generate, concatenate, get, etc two or more joins for use it in the select_from clause. Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

The final result should be like this in the from:

```
SELECT a.dev, b.asha, c.unk
FROM a 
    FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.dev = b.devicb 
    FULL OUTER JOIN c ON a.dev = c.devicc
WHERE 
    a.cust = 'SNTC' AND
    b.cust = 'SNTC' AND
    c.cust = 'SNTC' AND
    a.invent = '10' AND
    b.invent = '10' AND
    c.invent = '10'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you cannot have ORM models without primary keys, be they real or not. It'd seem you're using the core.

Comment: Yes, I have primary key in ORM, but not correct mapped

Comment: @IljaEverilä corrected the question, sorry. What do you mean  It'd seem you're using the core.?

Comment: [`select()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select), [`join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join), etc. are [Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) constructs. The 2 are not separate, though, but the ORM is built on top of Core.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way, just invoquing .join in the previous join but only using right table. `self._join.join(rightTable,...)`

Complete solution for the method:

```
def get_joins(self, first, leftTable, rightTable, leftTableColumn, rightTableColumn, outer):
    if first:
        self._join = join(leftTable, rightTable, leftTableColumn == rightTableColumn, full=outer)
        first = False
    else:
        self._join = self._join.join(rightTable, leftTableColumn == rightTableColumn, full=outer)
```